# Is this pointer safely declared?

Tags: c, pointers

The following code is within the same function:

```
File *curr = dir -> head_file;
...
f -> next = curr;
```

Is `f -> next` actually pointing to `dir -> head_file` or the local variable `curr`? As in, once this function exits, will there be an issue when `curr` disappears or points to something else?

Comment: Are you clear on how C assignment works?

Comment: @nneonneo I am mostly fine with C assignment, but I was unclear if changing `curr` would affect `f -> next`. I understand it now, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`f->next` is a copy of the value stored in `curr`. If `curr` changes, that will not affect `f->next` if nothing is assigned to the latter. Neither `curr` nor `f->next` ever point to `dir -> head_file`; they are both copies.

Answer (score 0):

```
 f -> next = curr;
```

Makes `f->next` points to where `curr` points to, in this case, it is `dir -> head_file`, it does not destroy the pointer `curr` or change the direction where `curr` points to.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe, it points to the `dir->header_file`.

Note the types and note that `&curr` has a type of `File **` which is different. To get an address of a variable you use `&`: `&curr`